# ocultar etiqueta con php y js

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer que se oculte un campo al presionar un botón con JS y php, son muchas dudas y estoy un poco verde por no decir demasiado.
No utilizo un form, utilizo un evento onclick de JS para presionar el botón y luego cambiar la variable SESSION para que el campo me aparezca oculto en lo que dure la sesion.

```
<?php

//Inicio sesión y nombro la variable

session_start();

$_SESSION['acceso'] = 'acceso';

    //Depende de variable SESSION presentamos un campo u otro
    function ocultarBarra() {

        if($_SESSION['acceso'] == 'acceso') {
            echo '<div id="barra" class="container text-center"> 
                <div id="mensaje" class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="aceptar">
                        <button class="col-md-2 btn btn-success" onclick="barra()">aceptar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="parcial">
                        <button class="col-md-2 btn btn-warning" 
                                       onclick="barra()">parciales</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cerrar">
                        <button class="col-md-2 btn btn-danger" onclick="barra()">denegar</button>
                    </div>
        </div>';
    }elseif($_SESSION['acceso'] == 'sinBarra') {            
        echo '<div id="barra" class="container text-center hidden"> </div>';            
    };
    
    }
    ocultarBarra();

    ?>

//Ocultamos barra JS y cambiamos variable SESSION para que la proxima vez aparezca oculta
<script>
    function barra() {
        document.getElementById('barra').className = 'hidden';
        <?php 
           $GLOBALS['acceso'] = "sinBarra"; 
          ?>;
        ocultarBarra();
     };     
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo quieres de acuerdo a lo que tenga esa variable mostrar o no una barra (no sé si será de navegación o a que te refieres).

hacerlo con sesiones no creo que sea tan recomendable, por lo que veo, supongo que quieres que esa configuración se guarde del lado del cliente, por lo que te sugiero guardarlo en el localStorage o en las cookies.

si lo quieres hacer con php podría utilizar [set cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php) y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_COOKIE["cookieBarra"])){
      setcookie('cookieBarra', $valorPredeterminado) //me imagino que el predeterminado será visible
     }

    if($_COOKIE["cookieBarra"] == 'visible'){
       echo '<div id="barra"></div> <div>tu otro contenido</div>'
    }else{
       echo '<div>tu otro contenido</div>'
    }
?>

<script>
//funcion que dependiendo del estado oculta o muestra la barra
    const ocultarBarra = ()=>{
        if(<?php echo $_COOKIE["cookieBarra"] ?> ===  'visible'){
           setcookie('cookieBarra', 'oculta');
           //ocultas la barra
        }else{
           setcookie('cookieBarra', 'visible');
           //muestras la barra
        }
     }  
    
    document.querySelector('#barra').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
       ocultarBarra();
    })
      
 </script>
```

aunque yo en mi caso lo haría todo con js, accediendo a las cookies por medio de [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie) y con [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) sacar la cookie y ya validar si el valor es visible u oculto, y dependiendo de eso, mostrar o no la barra.

ahora, supongo que quieres que esa información se guarde del lado del cliente, para que cuando vuelva a ingresar se mantenga la barra en el ultimo estado que lo dejó, pero si tu intención no es esa, sino que simplemente es mostrar o no la barra, pues te recomiendo que simplemente utilizes una variable que tome el estado de la barra, oculta o visible...

PD: no he probado el código, pero creo que sería algo parecido a eso, espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, sí, algo parecido, estoy probándolo y me da algunos errores, la verdad es que excede un poco los conocimientos que tengo no te  voy a mentir.

Comment: Si quería hacer algo como las cookies, lo intenté hacer con JS pero al tener la página en PHP al refrescar la página o irme a otra sección se me volvía a poner la barra. Desconocía que había una variable de cookies en PHP ya que es algo como eso lo que quería hacer, una barra de cookies para una página, el problema ya te digo que tengo es ese, que al refrescar o cambiar de sección me volvía a aparecer la barra.
Voy a trabajar sobre esto a ver si saco algo, muchísimas gracias compañero